# Set process variable in JBPM 6

Tags: java, jbpm

We are using JBPM 6.x and wanted to update process variables once process is in progress.

I have many example to access process variables in java code but nowhere clearly find how to set it in java code?

Just to give more background: We can set variables in process definition as

**kcontext.setVariable();**

How can we set in java code using API? OR how can get kContext? PLEASE HELP

Comment: Just to give more background: We can set variables in process definition as kcontext.setVariable(); How can we set in java code using API? OR how can get kContext? PLEASE HELP

Comment: Just wondering, are you using kie-server also? if so, there will a full-REST API documentation available. usually the URL is <ip address or localhost>:<port>/kie-server/docs
example:
123.123.123.123:8180/kie-server/docs

Comment: No I am not using Kie-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below approach:

```
 ProcessInstance processInstance= ksession.startProcess("com.sample.bpmn.hello",params);  
    RuleFlowProcessInstance ruleFlowProcessInstance= (RuleFlowProcessInstance) processInstance;
    ruleFlowProcessInstance.setVariable("processVar1","newValue");
```

Comment: Hi Abhijit, I an trying the same thing but getting error. Please help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50613721/proper-way-to-set-or-update-jbpm6-process-variables